# Wallets report 0 balance for address but balanceOf is right

Tags: solidity, wallets, erc-20, openzeppelin-contracts

Given this contract using Openzeppelin lib:

```
contract Token is StandardToken, Ownable {

    string public name = "";
    string public symbol = "";
    uint8 public decimals = 18;

    constructor(string _name, string _symbol, uint256 _supply, address creator) public {
        owner = creator;
        name = _name;
        symbol = _symbol;
        totalSupply_ = _supply;
        balances[owner] = totalSupply_;
        Transfer(0x0, owner, balances[owner]);
    }
```

> truffle(rinkeby)> Token.at('0xdc190d1ac0355bc3b9b4bba96738484cd07690ea').balanceOf.call('0xD587f68bE865c8a4F34CC2a53150dE0DA5771957'); BigNumber { s: 1, e: 2, c: [ 665 ] }

Metamask and Coinbase wallet report 0 balance when you add it as a custom token with the owner address.

Running truffle console, the owner is indeed correct and running balanceOf reports correct balance.

Is it a problem because it is assigned in the constructor and there is no transfer tx? So the problem is with the wallets or in my code?

The code passes all truffle tests for balances etc before deployed.

Note that this contract is deployed from a "mother" contract that's why owner is not msg.sender but why would that be a problem?

Tried updating with a Transfer event to be compatible with the ERC20 protocol but didn't change anything.

Comment: Are you sure you are checking token balance and not Ether balance? Also, OpenZeppelin doesn't have a variable `tokenURI_` as far as I know.

Comment: tokenURI is my addition but irrelevant. Yes I am checking from truffle console balanceOf(address) on the contract and it's above 0. Then I add it as a custom token in both Metamask and Coinbase Wallet and the balance is zero.

Comment: What network are you using? i guess you're sure that the network you use is the same? One thing you could try is emit a custom `Event` in the constructor with value of `balances[owner]` and see what it gives you.

Comment: Could you share truffle.js and command which you use to run truffle console?

Comment: truffle console --network rinkeby. Then Token.at('address').balanceOf.call('owneraddress') reports correct balance.

Comment: Do you want to share the contract address and owner address so we may try for ourselves?

Comment: sure yes. on rinkeby https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xdc190d1ac0355bc3b9b4bba96738484cd07690ea and the owner address is 0xD587f68bE865c8a4F34CC2a53150dE0DA5771957 and there is also an emmited event in the constructor. 
`truffle(rinkeby)> Token.at('0xdc190d1ac0355bc3b9b4bba96738484cd07690ea').balanceOf.call('0xD587f68bE865c8a4F34CC2a53150dE0DA5771957');
BigNumber { s: 1, e: 2, c: [ 665 ] }`

Comment: to be honest it is still not clear how you connect truffle to rinkeby, because truffle doesn't have predefined configurations, there are defined network ids only. could you share truffle config file?

Comment: Etherscan show a non zero balance https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/0xdc190d1ac0355bc3b9b4bba96738484cd07690ea?a=0xd587f68be865c8a4f34cc2a53150de0da5771957. It might be that etherscan do not update token balances for testnets frequently.

Comment: @Ismael that's what is driving me crazy. Etherscan is correct. Coinbase wallet and Metamask show 0.

Comment: @Aquila this is not the point since Etherscan reports balance correctly too but here you go ```rinkeby: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(
          mnemonic,
          "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/f0eca74029fc435a9709d267f3b8caca"
        );
      },```

Comment: @arisalexis The amount transfered is very small it is possible that Metamask will not show such small value. I cannot check coinbase.

Comment: @Ismael I updated an answer because ultimately you were right. Thanks

Comment: my balance is 2,277,013,208.347918119101191473 eMax, but my Value is $ 0 in MetaMask, what can i do? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that invoking the above constructor with a normal number from web3js 1.0 converts the uint initial_supply to a much smaller number.

Calling it with `web3.utils.toWei(number,"ether")` is working.

Metamask and coinbase wallet were reporting 0 because the number was too small.